# Scroll between sticky elements with prev/next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create some buttons that can scroll between some div elements. I know this can be done using scrollTop however the elements are sticky so the previous button will not scroll the element out of view.

Here is a JSfiddle to better understand what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/1uek576m/1/

and here's the script I already have:

```
(function() {
var scrollTo = function(element) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: element.offset().top
    }, 500);
}
$('#next').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $current = $('main > .current');
    if ($current.index() != $('main > .background').length - 1) {
        $current.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
        scrollTo($current.next());
    }
});
$('#prev').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $current = $('main > .current');
    if (!$current.index() == 0) {
        $current.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
        scrollTo($current.prev());
    }
});
})();
```

Is there any way to achive this ?

Edit: For clarification, I am using position: sticky on the block elements to achieve a scroll effect as demonstrated in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yk57cgZLWRo

Thank you

Comment: `if (!$current.index() == 0) {` is most likely a logical error.  This is saying take the value of the index, flip it's truthy value, and compare it to 0.  Most likely you intended to do `if ($current.index() != 0) {` which is comparing the index against 0

Comment: And just wondering: Why are you using `position: sticky` if those are not really sticky elements? Those elements should be just normal block elements and on click you're scrolling to the next or previous item.

Comment: I've edited my post to try and be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `position: sticky`. Because those are not sticky elements. The element should be just a normal block element, which they are by default. And then on click you're scrolling to the next or previous item.

To vertically center the content you could use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container). No need to position the `<h1>` with absolute.

```js
(function() {
    var scrollTo = function(element) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: element.offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
    $('#next').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $current = $('main > .current');
        if ($current.index() != $('main > .background').length - 1) {
            $current.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
            scrollTo($current.next());
        }
    });
    $('#prev').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $current = $('main > .current');
  if (!$current.index() == 0) {
            $current.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
            scrollTo($current.prev());
        }
    });
})();
```

```css
#scroll-menu {
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.background {
    background: green;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.background:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}

.background:nth-child(3) {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll-menu">
    <div class="container clear">
      <a id="prev" href="#">prev</a>
        <a id="next" href="#">next</a>
   </div>
</div>
    
<main role="main">
    <article class="background current">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="background">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="background">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Sorry, I perhaps should of explained better. I need position: sticky to create the desired scroll effect of each block overlapping each other. So I'm looking for a way to scroll between each block with position: sticky which the current script I have does not achieve.